# DNS Setup Questions

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, ubuntu-16.04

First question why is there a need to setup the dns resource records like A,MX in both the vps server and domain registrar?  Can resource record just exist on domain registrar?   Second question for the resource record A why do you need to enter a hostname like www?  can hostname be blank?

Comment: www is a subdomain, that for historical reasons appears at the start of many website URLs. You don't have to map that subdomain. If you do you could either use a CNAME (effectively an alias) or an A record and redirect to the root domain.

Comment: You need to configure your zone delegation once, this will include the NS records, beside that you do everything only in the (admin interface of) your authoritative name server. Similiar need to be configured to load your zone (it is typically set up automatically when you have a Hoster)

Comment: To reference the zone itself yountypically use a @ as your hostname, but it depends on the config interface of your provider if this is used, a empty hostname or a different section somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> First question why is there a need to setup the dns resource records
>   like A,MX in both the vps server and domain registrar?

Well, neither. Your DNS records need to be configured in whatever system is hosting your authoritative DNS. That might be the same organization as your registrar, but it might not me. Look at your domain `whois` records to see what your authoritative nameservers are.

> Second question for the resource record A why do you need to enter a
>   hostname like www? can hostname be blank?

Sure, `A` records can be created at the zone apex.